# Determine whether a body breaks due to mechanical stress

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

How to determine if a body breaks if I know ultimate tensile stress of that body, other mechanical properties of the material and Cauchy stress tensor applied to the body?

It is simple if only one diagonal component of Cauchy stress tensor is non-zero and it is positive,then I just have to compare this component to ultimate tensile strength.
It is simple if only one diagonal component of Cauchy stress tensor is non-zero and it is negative,then I just have to compare this component to ultimate compression strength.
It is simple if only one non-diagonal component of Cauchy stress tensor is non-zero,then I just have to compare this component to ultimate Shear strength.

Comment: In cases where the stress tensor is full you need to find what is called: the principal stresses, these are three values of the maximum normal stresses acting in three planes called principal planes. The principal stresses result from a transformation that guarantees zero shear stress.

Comment: So to decide whether the body breaks I must compare principal stress to ultimate strength of the material?

Comment: I tried to adress it in an answer.

Comment: You need to have a failure criterion, expressed in terms of the three principal stresses, which reduces to the uniaxial ultimate stress criterion for that type of loading.    Usually, this is expressed in terms of the sum of the squares of the principal stress differences.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer the question one should clarify the meaning of "brake". From the microscopic point of view failure is a very complex phenomenon and typically an energetic criterion are used to describe it. For metals, von Mises, Tresca, etc. are commonly used criterions.

This criterions are functions of the so called principal stresses. The principal stresses are the maximum normal stresses in a point of material; they are invariants of the stress tensor and are three for 3D problems. These normal stresses result from a rotational transformation of the (Cauchy) stress tensor and a subsequent derivation with respect to the angle of rotation in order to obtain its maxima orientation.

For linear elastic media, it is a common practice to compare the principal stresses to the elastic limit (or the yield stress). This is probably the approach you are looking for.

As for the case of normal stresses, maximum shear stresses can also be found; however, they should be compared to the yield shear stress.

Note that in the direction of the principal stresses the shear stress is always equal to zero. Therefore, in this coordinate system, the point is subjected to pure tension and compression.

For a detailed description see [Cauchy Stress Tensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor.)

Comment: Lets say I know 2 principal stresses sigma1 and sigma2. I also know  ultimate strength. Now how do I determine whether the body breaks?